# Vscode not showing password prompt when pulling with git ssh / specific port

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have my git repository set up with a remote url of this:

`ssh://username@remoteurl.com:1993/var/git/myrepo`

Git pull and push works fine, and correctly prompts me for my password. When trying to push/pull from Vscode, however, it shows the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is my git url correctly formatted? Is there a way to get both command line and Vscode push / pull to work?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS, on your private SSH key filename (`id_rsa`? `somethingElse_rsa`?) and if the private SSH key is passphrase protected or not.
(Not to mention your VSCode version, and your Git version)

For instance, regarding passphrase, see [issue 6202](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6202#issuecomment-236861431).
The support for private key is very much in progress, not yet released: [issue 13680](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13680#issuecomment-381771276).

To know more, launch `code` (VSCode) from a shell session where you have set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`.

You can then use the VSCode command: "`Git: Show Git output`" to see exactly what your ssh call is doing on `git pull/push` within VSCode.

Comment: Windows 10, VSCode version 1.23.1, git version 2.16.2. I don't have an SSH key, I'm using a plaintext password.

Comment: @claust you don't have an ssh key??? Using an URL starting with `ssh://` pretty much implies that you have a public and private ssh key, with the public one being published in `remoteurl.com:~username/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: I use an ssh:// url because I am using a nonstandard port. Otherwise git won't recognise the ':1993' part and will think it's part of the path

Comment: @claust I don't dispute that. I would like to know what you mean by "I don't have an SSH key", because that is needed for an SSH URL (port or no port)

Comment: I don't have an ssh private/public key set up for my private repository. It is a server that has simply a username / plaintext passphrase combination. When I use git on the command line with the above url, it works and prompts me for my plaintext password. I could put the port in git config to make it work without the ssh:// url, but I want this to be able to push regardless of what computer I'm working from.

Comment: @claust OK. Try my suggestion with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` set to `ssh -v`: you will see exactly what VSCode is doing regarding SSH.

Comment: Interesting. Simply setting the variable prompted me for the password. Without it, it doesn't prompt me.